# Apply a family of functions over nested list -R

Tags: r, for-loop, mapply

I need to apply a family of functions of form (a*x +b+ c) to 
a nested list, e.g. in following form

```
map_function <- function(x,y){
  return(linear_function(x[1],x[2],x[3],y))
}

linear_function <- function(x1,x2,x3,y){
  g <- sapply(y, function(x){x1*x+x2+x3})%>% min(.)
  return(g)
}
```

over two lists e.g. so that when map_function is passed on all arguments

```
pr_list <- list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)) and
f_list <- list(c(234,34),c(456,34,567),c(111,222))
```

It will generate a nested list/matrix of 3 with 2 values in each. What is the R-way to do it other than using `for` loop?

e.g. if the output is a matrix, examples of the elements will be

```
    M11 <- linear_function(pr_list[[1]][1],pr_list[[1]][2],pr_list[[1]][3],f_list[[1]] )
M12 <- linear_function(pr_list[[1]][1],pr_list[[1]][2],pr_list[[1]][3],f_list[[2]] )
M13 <- linear_function(pr_list[[1]][1],pr_list[[1]][2],pr_list[[1]][3],f_list[[3]] )

M21 <- linear_function(pr_list[[2]][1],pr_list[[2]][2],pr_list[[2]][3],f_list[[1]] )
M22 <- linear_function(pr_list[[2]][1],pr_list[[2]][2],pr_list[[2]][3],f_list[[2]] )
M23 <- linear_function(pr_list[[2]][1],pr_list[[2]][2],pr_list[[2]][3],f_list[[3]] )

M <- list(c(M11,M21),c(M12,M22),c(M13,M23))
print(M)

[[1]]
[1]  39 147

[[2]]
[1]  39 147

[[3]]
[1] 116 455
```

Comment: Hey, so what is pr_list and f_list?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you are trying to generate?

Comment: f_list[[1]] is a list with 2 elements. Should linear_function return 4 values?

Comment: linear_function would return 2 values M11 and M21

Comment: I am still not understanding your example input and outputs. Can you be more specific with the example?

Comment: edited with complete output

Answer (score 1):

This is my best guess for you.

```
x <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3), x2 = c(4,5,6))

y <- data.frame(y1 = c(234,34,NA),y2 = c(456,34,567), y3 = c(111,222,NA))

linear_function <- function(x, y){x[[1]]*y +x[[2]]+x[[3]]}
```

Which when applied like this, results in the following.

```
> linear_function(x$x1, y)
   y1  y2  y3
1 239 461 116
2  39  39 227
3  NA 572  NA
> linear_function(x$x2, y)
   y1   y2  y3
1 947 1835 455
2 147  147 899
3  NA 2279  NA
```

If you want a single object.

```
> z <- lapply(x, linear_function, y)
> z
$x1
   y1  y2  y3
1 239 461 116
2  39  39 227
3  NA 572  NA

$x2
   y1   y2  y3
1 947 1835 455
2 147  147 899
3  NA 2279  NA
```